# How to use assert with condition to check on every element in a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, assert

I am checking if a matrix is positive definite by computing the eigenvalues of the matrix.

```
matrix = np.array([[0.0070123 , 0.00578589, 0.01867008, 0.00351521, 0.00151787],
       [0.00578589, 0.00590836, 0.01657745, 0.00304733, 0.0013278 ],
       [0.01867008, 0.01657745, 0.0555186 , 0.01004483, 0.00439243],
       [0.00351521, 0.00304733, 0.01004483, 0.00270608, 0.00080408],
       [0.00151787, 0.0013278 , 0.00439243, 0.00080408, 0.00084371]])

eigenvalues = np.linalg.eievals(matrix)

Out[20]: array([0.06913077, 0.0004869 , 0.00057456, 0.0009318 , 0.00086503])
```

Apparently, this matrix is positive definite since all eigenvalues are greater than 0. Now I wish to use `assert` to make sure this matrix always stays positive definite, that is, all eigenvalues are greater than 0, since I will put this code into a function. I know `np.where` can be used to check on condition and return the desired output/elements, but I wonder if I can apply this with `assert`? Or is there any better way I can compute this?

Comment: Please note that `assert` is mainly used for debugging purpose, if you are to put it in a fuunction to be used you might better want to raise an error.

Comment: `assert all(eigenvalues > 0), 'matrix not positive definite'`

Comment: Yes you are right @paime, I am doing this to incur an error if the condition is not achieved

Comment: I would be more cautious here. If you depend on the matrix being positiv definite maybe you should also check if the matrix is functionally not pd. I.e. has eigenvalues so close to zero they may as well be zero. Something like adding a 2nd line with `assert not np.any(np.isclose(eigenvalues,0))` or check the values are bigger than some small value e.g. 1e-08 rather than zero. (that's the default absolute tolerance for np.isclose)

Comment: That's a good idea @user2640045 :D you can write your answer too. I think what you said is more feasible as indeed, when the size of matrix increases, there will be those eigenvalues that are too little to be greater than 0

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I think arnino answered the actual question perfectly and I only made a little remark. So in my opinion a comment is the perfect place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `np.all` which returns `True` if all elements of an array are `True` and returns `False` otherwise. More details in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

The following code should achieve what you want

```
assert np.all(eigenvalues > 0)
```

If you are trying to raise an error, you can use `np.any` which returns `True` if at least one element of the array is `True`

```
if np.any(eigenvalues <= 0):
    raise YourError
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
booleans = np.unique(np.any(eigenvalues > 0))
assert len(booleans) == 1 and booleans[0]
```

You'll first check if there is eigenvalues below zero, which will return a boolean array which you check the unique values of. If you have only True values you can check with the `.unique()` function to make sure that you have only one value in the array and that it's True so that you do not have a full negative eigenvalue matrix.